# installing nokogiri 1.8.2 (for Metaslpoit)

Tags: nokogiri

i have a problem with installing nokogiri 1.8.2 
it shows me this :

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  factory_bot_rails was resolved to 4.8.2, which depends on
    railties was resolved to 4.2.10, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 4.2.10, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 4.2.10, which depends on
          rails-dom-testing was resolved to 1.0.9, which depends on
            nokogiri

Comment: You're probably missing libraries. What happens when you do `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2'`?

Comment: opps ! 

install: cannot stat 'nokogiri': No such file or directory

Comment: No, gem install. Just copy the highlighted part of my comment.

Comment: sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2'

ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20180410-9717-8srl8p.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.8.2/gem_make.out

Comment: sounds like you need to `apt-get install ruby-dev` but I can't walk you through every step of this here.

Answer (score 4):

Could you try

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential liblzma-dev patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev
```